# Problems with randomizing again

Tags: c++, random, enums

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum Movement{STAND=1,WALK,RUN,CRAWL};

    srand(time(0));
    Movement state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

    cout << state << endl;

    switch(state)
    {
        /*Here the logic is,
         * 
         * 1. From stand, he can walk or crawl
           2. From Walk, he can stand or run
           3. From Run, he can walk
           4. From Crawl, he can stand
         */

        case STAND: 
            cout << "You can walk or crawl" << endl;        
            while(state==WALK || state==CRAWL)
            {
                state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
            }
            break;


        case WALK: 
            cout << "You can stand or run" << endl;
            while(state==STAND || state==RUN)
            {
                state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
            }
            break;


        case RUN: 
            cout << "You can walk" << endl;
            while(state==WALK)
            {
                state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
            }
            break;

        default: 
            cout << "You can stand" << endl;
            while(state==STAND)
            {
                state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
            }

    }

    }
}
```

I am using random, and expecting random results based on those given conditions. But I am getting the same result as below.

```
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
```

why is this? I have tried do..while loops as well. No good at all. Nothing is checking the conditions I have given in case statements. please help.

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip your while-loops to do-while.  The expressions are invalid as well for the checks (unless it was your intention they NOT match the text). The states, according to the *messages* are:

```
Stand ==> (Walk || Crawl)
Walk  ==> (Stand || Run)
Run   ==> (Walk)
Crawl ==> (Stand)
```

So the sections need to be changed to

1. Generate the new random number BEFORE checking it. and..
2. Not leave until a valid production is reached.

The latter part is important for the Run and Crawl states. Since they can only produce ONE valid result state, spinning a rand() call looking for that value makes no sense. Just set the new state and loop again.

Regarding (2) above:

```
    case WALK: 
        cout << "You can stand or run" << endl;
        while(state==STAND || state==RUN)
        {
            state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
        }
        break;
```

Becomes...

```
    case WALK: 
        cout << "You can stand or run" << endl;
        do {
            state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
        } while(state!=STAND && state!=RUN);
        break;
```

Regarding the Run and Crawl states:

```
    case RUN: 
        cout << "You can walk" << endl;
        state = WALK;
        break;

    default: // CRAWL 
        cout << "You can stand" << endl;
        state = STAND;
        break;
```

That leaves you one more to check yourself, which I leave to you.

Comment: Thanks! Do while also not needed, the condition in while loops was wrong! Why I didn't see that!!! Thank you

Comment: @Sepala If you want the next move to be random you need those do-while loops (two of them, one for STAND and one for WALK). The others to can be eliminated. And you do NOT need to have a rand-gen in the loop anywhere besides those two do-whiles, contrary to the popular opinion of others that answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Move `Movement state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);` into the `for` loop.

Corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum Movement{STAND=1,WALK,RUN,CRAWL};
    srand(time(0));

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

        Movement state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);

        cout << state << endl;

        switch(state)
        {
            /*Here the logic is,
             * 
             * 1. From stand, he can walk or crawl
               2. From Walk, he can stand or run
               3. From Run, he can walk
               4. From Crawl, he can stand
             */

            case STAND: 
                cout << "You can walk or crawl" << endl;        
                while(state==WALK || state==CRAWL)
                {
                    state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
                }
                break;


            case WALK: 
                cout << "You can stand or run" << endl;
                while(state==STAND || state==RUN)
                {
                    state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
                }
                break;


            case RUN: 
                cout << "You can walk" << endl;
                while(state==WALK)
                {
                    state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
                }
                break;

            default: 
                cout << "You can stand" << endl;
                while(state==STAND)
                {
                    state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);
                }

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
You can walk
1
You can walk or crawl
2
You can stand or run
1
You can walk or crawl
2
You can stand or run
3
You can walk
4
You can stand
2
You can stand or run
2
You can stand or run
4
You can stand

Press any key to continue
```

Comment: That will not solve her problem. none of her inner while-checks that filter repeat cases will properly execute. That *will* generate a stream of randoms, but thats it. The filtering she wants will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

you could also calculate your next step in your state machine something like this:

```
...

case STAND:
    cout << "You can walk or crawl" << endl;
    state = rand()%2 ? WALK : CRAWL;
    break;

...
```

Answer (score -2):

rand() function in C with constant seed always tend to give same 'random' value no matter what you do.

A better way is to write your own RandomGenerator function and use it

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int RandomGenerator(int min, int max) // Generate min < random int < max
{
  int randNum;
  srand(rand()*time(NULL));
  randNum = rand() % max + min;
  // printf(" Random number is %d \n", randNum);
  return randNum;
}
```

Also move your `Movement state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);` inside `for` loop

Comment: Yeah but he has used srand() with time() to avoid that. Also merely calling srand once in the beginning of program is the solution. Not a repeatedly called function with the rand * time return manipulation done above

Comment: srand(time(0)) will always seed with same random value and each execution would return same random number. srand(rand()*time(null)) gives more "random" results. Also there is problem with code too with random being outside for loop

Comment: Instead of that if you only call srand(time(0)) once in the beginning of the program and keep calling rand afterwards you are perfectly fine and getting a random number with each, rand call. You are right about rand being outside of loop, but you didn't mention that in the solution. People are just giving feedback based upon the written solution